# Priority in Aws Lambda when there are multiple SQS triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am having aws lambda with two sqs triggers: queue1 and queue2. Is it possible to make aws lambda to prioritise events from queue1 over queue2?

If yes, how can I do that. Please share any samples or documentation link for doing this.

Comment: Are queue1 and queue2 coming at the same time? Or do you want to suspend queue2 triggering lambda function for specific time (ex. wait 5 min) before queue1 comes?

Comment: @shimo Yes. Queue1 and Queue2 are coming at the same time. But if there are any events in queue1, I want my lambda to trigger only that events and not trigger events from queue2 until all events in queue1 are consumed.

Comment: Is there a reason to not have two different Lambda's, one for each queue?  If queue1 is the priority then set the Lambda for queue2 to have just a single instance.

Comment: @stdunbar I can have two lambdas but I don't want to maintain two lambdas separately. I am looking for a solution if one lambda can handle my use case.

Answer (score 0):

We point both queues to the same Lambda Function. When the function is invoked, check if its source is the priority queue. If it is, process it. If it isn't, check if messages are available on the priority queue. If there are, return the current message to its queue. If there aren't, process the message. Repeat.
https://bitesizedserverless.com/bite/implement-the-priority-queue-pattern-with-sqs-and-lambda/

Comment: beware the in-flight message limit